# Wordpress on GAE - wp_admin URL not responding

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, google-app-engine

Followed the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress) to deploy wordpress onto GAE but /wp_admin/ does not responds although I added

```
- url: /wp-admin/
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/index.php
  secure: always
```

Also, when I change permalinks format .httaccess does not have writting permissions. How to solve this?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: `/wp_admin/` will not work, use `/wp-admin/`

Comment: Ohh gosh.. it was too easy. I got SSL connection error now. Although I tried to follow the instructions to configure it the tab for this never shows up. I guess it's discussion of another thread. Thanks

Comment: If using a custom domain remove the secure:always unless you have uploaded a cert. The instructions that Google gives on wordpress assume you are going to use the appspot domain.

Answer (score 1):

.httaccess won't work at all with App Engine. You have to use app.yaml to specify all your redirection handlers.

secure: always for /wp-admin/ and wp-login.php enforces https:// SSL protocol for WordPress backend, but it won't work out of the box with your custom domain.

So if you ported your site from other hosting and migrated database, you would need to change your wp_options table - siteurl value to https://your-app-name.appspot.com/ in order to log into WordPress backend.